# Converting a SHAPEFILE (SHP) to KML for google fusion table

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables, shapefile

I'm using http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html to convert a SHP file to a KML for integration into Google Fusion Tables.
I'm able to do this successfully with many shp files, but am having a particular problem with one particular SHP file.

http://www.electionsquebec.qc.ca/documents/zip/shapefile-sections-de-vote-elections-generales-2008.zip

When I create the KML file and open it in Google Earth, the actual boundaries are somewhere in the Pacific Ocean (rather than actually outlining the province of Quebec). The shape is fine, it's just the whole actual shape is shifted to the Pacific Ocean. I'm wondering if it has to do with the UTM..or something with the coordinates. I've tried different zones, different Datum...nothing works. Help?

Answer (score 0):

I used [shpescape](http://www.shpescape.com/), it gave me [this](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S597005TUVP) which looks right to me.  you must be doing something wrong with shp2kml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar w/shp2kml but according to the homepage it can accept Lat/Lng, or UTM based projections.  The shapefile in question, however, is in a Lambert equal area projection, which I assume is not supported (check the .prj file to see details).

As noted in the other answer, shpescape.com should work for this use case -- it does transformations with the proj4 library, and this projection is supported.

Comment: You both are right, this is great thank you. The only problem is shpescape.com seems to only process a max of 100 rows and my file has 125... any worksarounds? Thanks again guys.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just as a comment, shpescape stops at 100,000 features (not 100)